# jQuery UI draggable and sortable not working like I want it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

HI all. You can see the code right here: http://jsbin.com/egixa5/5/edit. I'm trying to make it so when I drag an article, it only puts it between each article, not the elements inside each article. Also, I'm not sure why it's duplicating the content, instead of just dragging and dropping it…

Any ideas? I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to make it so when I drag an article, it only puts it between each article, not the elements inside each article.

Change `$("#main").find('article').sortable(...)` to `$("#main").sortable(...)`.

> Also, I'm not sure why it's duplicating the content, instead of just dragging and dropping it…

That would be the `helper: clone` bit.

---

I think you basically just want to model your code after [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/placeholder.html).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Matt. I'll mark your answer when SO allows me to. somehow just missed that demo.